# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable - Problem with multiple return statements

Tags: python, return, typeerror, nonetype

I'm currently working on a crypto project, my goal is to generate private / public keys.
Except that I have a small problem when calling my function to generate the keys: ***public_key_gen (p, q)***

What I want to get are the values of the variables **n, e and d**, so I set a return to be able to get those values, but when I call my function with: **n, e, d = public_key_gen (p, q)**

I get 2 things:

- Either the program "works" and I get the following output:

```
n value is 123578373181123655208343175636804292271173681785256883444327640870974931349341262710288580905788539638259767347478584796837326764084700481097115020300102632379561717007649885185754820119595275727156024668970568307022090622838609976311599764597253379796776528961079420362490124189841815150240762537592043001761
e value is 11832064726698624148280543988640366830755204739317241252270141958146388467719173123121107019581147653443798869191623179152898217489119847977121749690617908086194173839455655360738148030443366462386968262480246186091156483777010384581676610002147549362802784706300598105182510294886795554917923170628898209451
d value is 21642295896417612716069232930599472754953273205000168713881079087094283598363672555171755782030552488783576912491633300644176925993602513100627986784648275367493264150010525404982139393867489834722050710309549067912384027344757177271292850873301973104790489815315442970067306383654891316158361377920843257059
```

- Or i get the following **NoneType Error**

```
n, e, d = public_key_gen(p, q)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

I have been stuck on this error for several days, I think the error comes from the return statement ***"return n, e, d"*** or **another return,**
(maybe in `if test_miller_rabin(e, 100) != True and coprime(e, totient) != True: public_key_gen(p, q)` ?)but what I don't understand is that sometimes my program works , but sometimes not and I get the error.

Here is my code below and a big thank in advance for those who will help me !

**EDIT:** Thanks a lot for the help, the other topic attached solved my problem, it was the absence of return to the loop "**if test_miller_rabin (e, 100)! = True and coprime (e, totient)! = True:** ", who caused the error. A return for the call solved the problem.

```
#Uses python3

import math
import random

q = 7860609810349437997613157248434027871225250583287443607923454620104266752600078759036968273486937999735557865438242994999893143564463424043665587717476383


p = 15721219620698875995226314496868055742450501166574887215846909240208533505200157518073936546973875999471115730876485989999786287128926848087331175434952767


g = 14799733099685290069112538652596243128703239961953845701446421910245263808674096745002413332176485093035372927607425310274867257978919240096025747777500681

r = random.randrange(1, p - 1)

def test_miller_rabin(n, k):
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    r = 0
    s = n - 1
    while s % 2 == 0:
        r += 1
        s //= 2
    for _ in range(k):
        a = random.randrange(2, n - 1)
        x = pow(a, s, n)
        if x == 1 or x == n - 1:
            continue
        for _ in range(r - 1):
            x = pow(x, 2, n)
            if x == n - 1:
                break
        else:
            return False
    return True


def gcd(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a


def coprime(a, b):
    return gcd(a, b) == 1


def public_key_gen(p, q):
    n = p * q

    totient = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
    e = random.randrange(2, totient - 1)

    if test_miller_rabin(e, 100) != True and coprime(e, totient) != True:
        public_key_gen(p, q)

    else:
        #Modular inverse

        d = pow(e, -1, totient)

        #var = [n, e, d]
        #return var
        # I tried with a list (var) and "return var" but without success

        return n, e, d




n, e, d = public_key_gen(p, q)

print("n value is", n)
print("e value, is", e)
print("d value is", d)
```

Comment: What is the point of the recursive call to `public_key_gen()`?  You're passing the same values for `p` and `q` as in the original call.

Comment: Hello John, my goal is to have "e" prime and co-prime with "totient", so in case I don't get "e" prime and co-prime with "totient", I re-call the function, but i agree that this is a "dirty" way of solving the problem. If you have another solution I'm very interested in it, I'm hardly experienced with python